# Extract string before certain string

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, substring

i want to get the string before a series of certain characters or substrings.
For instance, i have

```
unsigned char KeyStr[BUFFER_SIZE] = "-#NOT#"

unsigned char SomeStr[BUFFER_SIZE] = "this is the string i want to extract-#NOT#"
```

From above char array, i want to get `this is the string i want to extract` .
I want to get any string before `-#NOT#` or `KeyStr`.

I know i can use `strstr` to check if `KeyStr` exist in `SomeStr` or not, but how do i go about extracting string before `KeyStr`.
I can't use strtok cause as far as i know, it checks for delimeter and not substring.

I'm new to C, so absolutely clueless. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: C or C++? C++ has some neat functions, but you seem to be fixed on C functions.

Comment: You also seem to be fixed on C "strings".  The only thing mentioned in this question that's not C is _"I'm new to C++"_.  Are you perhaps learning C and not C++?

Comment: Yea actually i am using unsigned char[] rather than `string`. But most of other code is c++. So, basically i need a C solution for this. I've been stuck at it for quite sometime. :(

Comment: "*But most of other code is c++. So, basically i need a C solution for this.*" That's the opposite of a logical conclusion. If you're writing C++ code, you need a C++ solution.

Comment: @Shrey "Yea actually i am using unsigned char[] rather than `string`." May I ask why?

Comment: Why `unsigned char`? That makes all the standard C string functions (e.g. `strstr`) annoying to use (need casts everywhere).

Comment: My professor gave us a sample code, that we have to use to build our solution. The code is basically in C++ for UDP file trasnfer, except the data types it use is unsigned char[ ].

Comment: `unsigned char[]` is a C++ type. You're working in C++.

Comment: "how do i go about extracting string before KeyStr" --> `sprintf(destination, "%.s", (int) (strstr(SomeStr, KeyStr) - SomeStr), SomeStr);` is close with some added checking to key presence.  Yet you really need to choose one C or C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>1</sup>: (I'm going to assume you have good reason to use `unsigned char` for your buffers instead of `char`, and for why you are using old-style C functions in C++ instead of using modern C++ methods).

Like you said in your question, you can use `strstr()` to find the token.  Once you find the token, you can use simple pointer arithmetic to know how many characters to copy, using `strncpy()` to make the actual copy, eg:

```
unsigned char KeyStr[BUFFER_SIZE] = "-#NOT#";
unsigned char SomeStr[BUFFER_SIZE] = "this is the string i want to extract-#NOT#";

unsigned char *found = (unsigned char*) strstr((char*)SomeStr, (char*)KeyStr);
if (!found) ...

unsigned char extracted[BUFFER_SIZE];
strncpy((char*)extracted, (char*)SomeStr, found - SomeStr);
```

Now, with that said, please do consider using actual C++ techniques instead of C:

```
std:string KeyStr = "-#NOT#";
std::string SomeStr = "this is the string i want to extract-#NOT#";

std::string::size_type index = SomeStr.find(KeyStr);
if (index == std::string::npos) ... 

std::string extracted = SomeStr.substr(0, index);
```

Comment: This was helpful. :) Thanks @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1):

C++ has some neat functions, but as you seem to be using C strings and C methods I'll give a C answer. For the most part substring searching in C has to be implemented manually. However I'll give you an naive approach for this simple example. One thing you could do is iterate through your string and look for matching characters. If a matching character is found, then you can look at the next characters and see if they correspond to the next characters in the keyString. Something along the lines of:

```
int simpleSubStrSearch(char * st1, char * needle) {
 int i;
 int i2;
 int j;
 int subStrIndex = 0;
 int haystackSize = strlen(st1);
 int needleSize = strlen(needle);
 int succeed = 1;
 for (i = 0; i < haystackSize; i++) {
     if (*(st1 + i) == *needle) /*Tests if the ith character equals the first character in the string we are looking for*/ {
         subStrIndex = i;
         j = 0;
         for (i2 = i; i2 < needleSize; i2++) { /*If so, then we continue looping unless the characters no longer match up*/
             if (*(st1 + i2) == '\0') return -1; /*Return if its the end of the string*/
             else if (*(st1 + i2) != *(needle + j)) { /*If characters no longer match in the haystack and needle string*/
                 succeed = 0;
                 break;
             }
             j++;
         }
         if (succeed) return subStrIndex;
     }
     else if (*(st1 + i) == '\0') return -1;
  }
}
```

From there you can just take the index returned by this function, and as long as it's not -1 (needle not found) you can use a memcpy to copy the part of the string you want.

```
int index = simpleSubStrSearch(someStr, keyStr);
if (index > 0) {
    char * noKey = (char*)malloc(index + 1);
    memcpy(noKey, someStr, index);
    *(noKey + index) = '\0'; /*Remember the null terminator*/
    printf("Succeeded: %s \n", noKey);
    free(noKey);
}
```

Obviously this is not an efficient way of doing it, so I'll leave it up to you to explore better substring algorithms. If you are in fact using C++, then the easiest way to do this would be using `std::string` and its `substr()` and `indexOf()` methods to substring from the beginning of the std::string to the index of the keyString.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but this is how i implemented the solution.

```
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
strcpy((char*)buffer, "this is the worst way possible to do this-yaL8r");

unsigned char ExtractedStr[BUFFER_SIZE] = "";
printf(">> %s\n", buffer);

// "-yaL8r" is the Key string
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen((char*)buffer); i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] == '-' && buffer[i + 1] == 'y' && buffer[i + 2] == 'a' && buffer[i + 3] == 'L' && buffer[i + 4] == '8'
        && buffer[i + 5] == 'r')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        ExtractedStr[i] = buffer[i];
    }
}

printf(">> %s\n", ExtractedStr);
```